# How to remove the enclosing parentheses with macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

No comma is allowed in a macro argument because it will be treated as more than one arguments and the preprocessing will be wrong. However, we can parenthesize the argument to let preprocessor treat it as one argument. Is there a macro or other techniques which can remove the enclosing parentheses?

For example, if I define a macro like

```
#define MY_MACRO(a, b)   ...
```

and use it like

```
MY_MACRO( A<int, double>, text );
```

will be wrong. use it like

```
MY_MACRO( (A<int, double>), text)
```

with a macro or technique to remove the parentheses will be fine. Boost provides `BOOST_IDENTITY_TYPE` macro for only types but not general cases

Comment: A work around - `typedef A<int, double> IA; MY_MACRO(IA, text);`

Comment: The typedef is more elegant than all the preprocessor hacks IMHO

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#define ESC(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

then

```
MY_MACRO( ESC(A<int, double>), text );
```

might do what you want.

Comment: Wow. So nice and simple!

Comment: alternatively the ESC can go in MY_MACRO, e.g. `#define MY_MACRO(a,b) ESC a (b)`   `MY_MACRO( (A<int,double>), text );` --> `A<int,double> (text);` (variable declaration)

Answer (score 16):

This macro trick is similar to Yakk's solution but removes the need to explicitly pass in another macro as a parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _Args(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define STRIP_PARENS(X) X
#define PASS_PARAMETERS(X) STRIP_PARENS( _Args X )

int main()
{
  printf("without macro %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", (5,6,7,8,9,10) ); // This actually compiles, but it's WRONG
  printf("with macro %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", PASS_PARAMETERS((5,6,7,8,9,10)) ); //Parameter "pack" enclosed in parenthesis
  return 0;
}
```

Of course you could get creative by making the PASS_PARAMETERS macro into a variadic macro and pass in multiple parameter packs.

Comment: This is a good answer. The important part to understand is that the `_Args` macro does **not** wrap the `X` in `()`. This way, it concatenates and resolves the parentheses naturally.

Answer (score 14):

### Only maybe removing parentheses:

If you need to strip one layer of parenthesis, *but only if there are parenthesis to strip*, this longer set of macros does the trick:

```
#define DEPAREN(X) ESC(ISH X)
#define ISH(...) ISH __VA_ARGS__
#define ESC(...) ESC_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ESC_(...) VAN ## __VA_ARGS__
#define VANISH
```

This may be needed if you want to use `MY_MACRO` for different sets of datatypes:

```
#define MY_MACRO(a, b) DEPAREN(a), b

MY_MACRO( ({x, y, z}), text )
//> {x,y,z}, text

MY_MACRO( singlearg, text )
//> singlearg, text
```

### How it works:

We start with `DEPAREN(X) ESC(ISH X)`. If X has parenthesis, we get `ESC(ISH(X))`. If X does not have parenthesis, we get `ESC(ISH X)`.

We then expand `ESC(...)` into `ESC_(__VA_ARGS__)`, which expands the interior.

`ISH(...)` turns into `ISH __VA_ARGS__`, which strips one layer of parentheses from X. Now, regardless of whether or not X originally had parenthesis, we have `ESC_(ISH X)`.

We now need to get rid of `ISH`. However, because we already defined `ISH(...)`, we can't also define it as `#define ISH`  . That's why we concatenate it with another token (`VAN`) to get `VANISH X`.

`VANISH` is defined as  , so we are finally left with `X`, sans parentheses.

Comment: That's really genius!

Answer (score 2):

A simple hack could be to use variadic macros:

```
#define MY_MACRO(a, b...)   ...
```

Then you can use it like:

```
MY_MACRO(text, A<int, double>)
```

The comma in the second argument is still interpreted as the argument separator (meaning the macro is actually called with three arguments), but it's expanded inside the macro, making the behavior the same. The variadic argument has to be last in the macro, however.