# Generate a set of tagged and indexed specializations of a class template using Boost.Preprocessor

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, template-specialization, boost-preprocessor

There is a need to create a macro to generate a set of overloadings of a struct specialized by tag and index. I tried the following:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>

template< typename /*tag*/, int /*index*/ >
struct S;

#define GEN(ignored, tilda, index, type_name) \
    template<> struct S< struct BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name), index > \
    { BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(type_name) BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name); };

#if 1
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(GEN, ~, ((int)(i)))
#else
// above should be equiv to:
template<> struct S< struct i, 0 > { int i; };
#endif

int main()
{
    S< i, 0 >{}.i; // check if accessible
}
```

But get an error:

```
prog.cc:8:111: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 #define GEN(ignored, tilda, index, type_name) template<> struct S< struct BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name), index > { BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(type_name) BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name); };
                                                                                                               ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp:85:66: note: in expansion of macro 'GEN'
 # define BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_I(r, macro, data, seq, i, sz) macro(r, data, i, BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(seq))
                                                                  ^~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp:80:49: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_I'
 #    define BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_IM(r, im) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_I(r, im)
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp:79:45: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_IM'
 #    define BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M(r, x) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_IM(r, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_5 x)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp:79:77: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_5'
 #    define BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M(r, x) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M_IM(r, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_5 x)
                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp:32:31: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_M'
 # define BOOST_PP_IIF_1(t, f) t
                               ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/detail/for.hpp:22:37: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_FOR_1_C'
 # define BOOST_PP_FOR_1(s, p, o, m) BOOST_PP_FOR_1_C(BOOST_PP_BOOL(p(2, s)), s, p, o, m)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_FOR_1'
 #    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                  ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp:32:31: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_DETAIL_CHECK_EXEC'
 # define BOOST_PP_IIF_1(t, f) t
                               ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp:30:55: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_DETAIL_CHECK'
 #    define BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(macro, data, seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I_DETAIL_CHECK(macro, data, seq)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:10:1: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I'
 BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(GEN, ~, ((int)(i)))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:6:8: note: provided for 'template<class, long unsigned int <anonymous> > struct S'
 struct S;
        ^
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:16:8: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
     S< i, 0 >{}.i; // check if accessible
        ^
prog.cc:16:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     S< i, 0 >{}.i; // check if accessible
             ^
```

It seems, that `struct BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name)` part of macro cannot be handled correctly, but why? If I replace first occurrence of `BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name)` with `i`, then code compiles fine.

What is the source of an error?

Comment: Mmh, I'm not sure what you mean... Did I break something?

Comment: Oh! That's code block formatting, with the `<!-- language: lang-none -->` hint to remove colors :)

Comment: @Quentin I interesting in how to recover original tabulations in citations (which begins from `>` mark).

Comment: @GuyGreer It is declared in template specialization actual parameter list (if I name it correctly). `struct i` here: `template<> struct S< struct i, 0 > { int i; };`. Please, try to compile `#if 0` version.

Comment: @GuyGreer you are wrong. Just try what I said and all doubts will be disappeared.

Comment: I tried it and it indeed worked, which just makes me wonder more.  Regardless, that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Orient I've seen people mentioning that SO does not like tabs. I don't see any in your original question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `#include <cstdint>` for brevity's sake, but try compiling with -P -E which will output just the result of the preprocessor run, which is quite valuable when debugging Boost.PP programs.

The output of that is:

```
template< typename , int >
struct S;
template<> struct S< struct (i), 0 > { int (i); };
int main()
{
    S< i, 0 >{}.i;
}
```

from which the error is immediately obvious: `struct (i)` and `int (i)` are invalid syntax.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24481810/1277769) might help you with what to do about that.

Here's my solution to this, which is to create my own little tuple-accessing macros:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>

template< typename /*tag*/, int /*index*/ >
struct S;

#define FIRST(a, b) a
#define SECOND(a, b) b

#define GEN(ignored, tilda, index, type_name)                           \
    template<> struct S< struct SECOND type_name, index > \
    { FIRST type_name SECOND type_name; };

#if 1
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(GEN, ~, ((int, i)))
#else
// above should be equiv to:
template<> struct S< struct i, 0 > { int i; };
#endif

int main()
{
    S< i, 0 >{}.i; // check if accessible
}
```

Comment: `int (i);` is nice syntax even in function parameter list. But seems you find the error source.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: It is strange, because documentation on boost PP said, that `BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL` sould return unparenthesed element of tuple.

Comment: @orient I have no idea why it's not working, other attempts at removing the parenthesis have also failed.  I don't know enough about the rules in that case to be able to say whether this is a GCC bug or a Boost.PP bug

Comment: @Orient Ah!  I just noticed in the docs that `BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL` expands to `(b)(c)` in the example, which is a sequence again (which makes sense).  In your case, even though you have 1 element left in the tail  you will still get a sequence with one element in it, which you need to access with `BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD`.  That's what was happening

Comment: Seems it is a bug of `BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL`, which I can replace with `BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(*))`

Comment: 1 second difference =)

Comment: So, *tail* is not a *last*, though *head* is a *first*.